# Enable/disable a button based on count in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I have a view controller with a button that I'd like to enable if `myArray.count > 0`. I got KVO working initially, but it doesn't update.

My button property declared here:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;
```

I'd like to enable/disable the button based on the count of items in an array:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

Items are added/removed to the array via `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

I found a couple of posts on the topic of observing an NSMutableArray, every post I've seen seems enormous amount of code to implement something so simple.

I added this to `viewDidLoad` after `myArray` is instantiated:

```
// Add KVO for array
[self.saveButton addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myArray" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial) context:nil];
```

I added this method to do something when there's a change to `myArray`:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myArray"]) {
        if (self.myArray.count > 0) {
            NSLog(@"KVO: myArray.count > 0");
            [self.saveButton setEnabled:YES];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"KVO: myArray.count is ZERO");
            [self.saveButton setEnabled:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

I know I'm missing something simple, but what is proving elusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only time the array can be edited is through `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` then why not just enable/disable the button there.

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    //current code    

    if (self.myArray.count > 0) {
        NSLog(@"KVO: myArray.count > 0");
        [self.saveButton setEnabled:YES];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"KVO: myArray.count is ZERO");
        [self.saveButton setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew the answer would be simple, but WOW! I'm a moron. Thank you!

Comment: Haha, we've all been there ;)

Answer (score 0):

The catch is that NSMutableArray don't respect KVO, so observing the key path count won't work.This WILL work if you access the array correctly:

```
something = [self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"a"]; 
[something addObject:foo];
```

you may get answer at here :
[KVO With NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976577/kvo-with-nsmutablearray)

[Observing count in NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059279/observing-count-in-nsmutablearray)

For chinese  [Observing count in NSMutableArray]
you may get answer at :

change

```
// Add KVO for array
[self.saveButton addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myArray" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial) context:nil];
```

to

```
// Add KVO for array
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myArray" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial) context:nil];
```